# Swift: Recursive Value Type

Tags: ios, swift, value-type

I have a structure in which I want to have a global variable of type Struct?. This example is essentially a briefer version of the structure I am actually creating.

```
struct SplitString { //splits a string into parts before and after the first "/"

    var preSlash: String = String()
    var postSlash: SplitString? = nil

    init(_ str: String) {
        var arr = Array(str)
        var x = 0
        for ; x < arr.count && arr[x] != "/"; x++ { preSlash.append(arr[x]) }
        if x + 1 < arr.count { //if there is a slash
            var postSlashStr = String()
            for x++; x < arr.count; x++ {
                postSlashStr.append(arr[x])
            }
            postSlash = SplitString(postSlashStr)
        }
    }

}
```

However, it throws the error:

```
Recursive value type 'SplitString' is not allowed
```

Is there any way to get around this? Any help would be great. Thanks :)

Edit:
In case it is relevant, I am programming on iOS, not OSX.

Edit:
If I have:

```
var split = SplitString("first/second/third")
```

I would expect split to be:

```
{preSlash = "first", postSlash = {preSlash = "second", postSlash = {preSlash = "third",
postSlash = nil}}}
```

Comment: @Bryan Chen I realize I can do that. However, it more suits my purposes to use a value type rather than a reference type.

Comment: Can you not just user components separated by string? I.e. `let array = str.componentsSeparatedByString("/")` that will take your string and put it into an array separating by the slash.

Comment: @Fogmeister I don't believe there is a method called that. I check in a playground and it didn't appear on the list of methods.

Comment: [`componentsSeparatedByString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:) is a method. To use it you need to `import Foundation` in your playground first. You could also use Swift's [`split`](http://swifter.natecook.com/func/split/) function: `let array = split(str, { $0 == "/" })`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR:

What you are trying to achieve is easily accomplished using split:

```
for s in split("first/second/third", { c in c == "/" } ) {
    println("\(s)")
}
```

### Discussion:

It seems like you are trying to write a linked list of value types.  The problem is that Swift couples the concepts of copy semantics with value / reference access. (unlike say C++ which allows you to create the same object on the stack or heap).  The solution would seem to be wrapping it in a reference container aka class.

```
class SplitString { //splits a string into parts before and after the first "/"

    var preSlash: String = String()
    var postSlash: Wrapped? = nil

    init(_ str: String) {
        var arr = Array(str)
        var x = 0
        for ; x < arr.count && arr[x] != "/"; x++ { preSlash.append(arr[x]) }
        if x + 1 < arr.count { //if there is a slash
            var postSlashStr = String()
            for x++; x < arr.count; x++ {
                postSlashStr.append(arr[x])
            }
            postSlash = Wrapped(postSlashStr)
        }
    }

}

class Wrapped {
    var split:SplitString

    init(var _ str:String) {
        split = SplitString(str)
    }
}
```

Note that this code compiles as a proof of concept but I haven't delved into your algorithm or tested it.

### Edit:

In response to your edits above, this code will exercise your code above and yield the splits you want:

```
for (var s:SplitString? = split; s != nil; s = s?.postSlash?.split) {
    println("\(s!.preSlash)")
}
```

Obviously having [turtles all the way down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down) doesn't make sense, per the discussion above, so you need to break the cycle, as was the case with the class containing your struct.

Note that I have been trying to answer the question that you posted, not the problem that you have.  The solution to the problem that you have, is to use SequenceOf and GeneratorOf to create a sequence wrapped generator that iterates through the slashes and returns the substrings between.  This is actually done for you via the split function:

```
for s in split("first/second/third", { c in c == "/" } ) {
    println("\(s)")
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The same error still occurs. I believe that your code compiled because you are using class, but I am using structures.

Comment: You can't keep doing the same thing and expect a different result.  Can you update your question with a test case and expected result?

Answer (score 8):

I imagine this is because an Optional behaves like a value type.
So what you have is a value type of a value type. A value type.

In order to do layout for a value type, you need to know the size of things involved.

So you have (simplified):

```
sizeof(SplitString) = sizeof(String) + sizeof(SplitString?)
```

with

```
sizeof(SplitString?) > sizeof(SplitString)
```

since you need to store the fact that the value is or is not present (and, no, a pattern of sizeof(SplitString) zeros is not a valid representation for that as it would be for a class type - why? imagine Int? = 0)

So, now you have

```
sizeof(SplitString?) > sizeof(String) + sizeof(SplitString?)
```

but all quantities involved are definitely > 0. Rather the absurd, right?